# NSInternalInconsistencyException After Barcode Scan on .NET MAUI app

Tags: maui

I'm using the ZXing MAUI package to scan QR codes in my .NET MAUI app. This was working before but it now crashes the app with the `NSInternalInconsistencyException` error.

Specifically, it shows this reason:

> Reason: Modifications to the layout engine must not be performed from
> a background thread after it has been accessed from the main thread.

The control looks like this on the page:

```xml
<zxing:CameraBarcodeReaderView
    Grid.Row="0"
    x:Name="Scanner"
    IsDetecting="True"
    IsTorchOn="False"
    BarcodesDetected="QrCode_Detected"
    HeightRequest="300"
    WidthRequest="300"
    HorizontalOptions="CenterAndExpand"
    VerticalOptions="CenterAndExpand"/>
```

The code behind looks like this and because I use a view model with this page, I call the VM from code behind:

```cs
private void QrCode_Detected(object sender, ZXing.Net.Maui.BarcodeDetectionEventArgs e)
{
    var value = e.Results[0].Value;
    
    Scanner.IsDetecting = false;
    
    Dispatcher.Dispatch(async () =>
    {
        await _vm.QrCodeScannedAsync(value);
    });
}
```

And in my view model, I make an API call to get some result which I then display on the screen:

```cs
using Plugin.Maui.Audio;
    
public partial class MyViewModel : BaseViewModel
{
    //...
    [ObservableProperty]
    string message;
    
    public async Task QrCodeScannedAsync(string value)
    {
        try
        {
            var result = await _myApi.GetScanResult(value);
            if(result.IsValid)
            {
                Message = "Congratulations!";
                var audioPlayer = _audioManager.CreatePlayer(await FileSystem.OpenAppPackageFileAsync("success.mp3"));
                audioPlayer.Play();
            }
            else
            {
                Message = "Sorry! Invalid code!";
                var audioPlayer = _audioManager.CreatePlayer(await FileSystem.OpenAppPackageFileAsync("error.mp3"));
                audioPlayer.Play();
            }
        }
        catch(Exception e)
        {
            // Handle error but I never hit this
        }
    }
}
```

Is this because I set the `Message` after getting the scan result which updates the UI?

Comment: use `MainThread`

Comment: Where? Just for setting the `Message`? I make an API call so that needs to happen in background. Do a `MainThread.BeginInvokeOnMainThread()` just for setting `Message` value?

Comment: What changed since the last time it worked?

Comment: I don't know because I don't know what the stack trace of the exception is.  But the error message is a pretty clear indicator that `MainThread` is the fix.

Comment: @ewerspej Nothing's changed in this code block since the last time it worked. There's been quite a few updates elsewhere in the code and some nuget package updates. So, I'm wondering if any of the nuget updates have anything to do with it.

Comment: Did you step through the code in the debugger? Which line causes the error? I would agree with Jason that the error message is quite clear about the MainThread.

Comment: I'm again having problems with HotReload so as we speak,  I'm doing a quick build to test using `MainThread` for the `Message` update and will test it through TestFlight. Will post the result here.

Comment: Setting the value of `Message` within a `MainThread.BeginInvokeOnMainThread()` fixed the issue.  See update section in original post. Thank you for your help.

Comment: FYI: The code that fixes it would be better as an answer, instead of an update to question.

Answer (score 0):

Placing the section of the code that impacts the UI within `MainThread.BeginInvokeOnMainThread()` fixed the issue -- see below:

```
using Plugin.Maui.Audio;

public partial class MyViewModel : BaseViewModel
{
    //...
    [ObservableProperty]
    string message;

    public async Task QrCodeScannedAsync(string value)
    {
        try
        {
            var result = await _myApi.GetScanResult(value);
            if(result.IsValid)
            {
                var audioPlayer = _audioManager.CreatePlayer(await FileSystem.OpenAppPackageFileAsync("success.mp3"));
                audioPlayer.Play();

                MainThread.BeginInvokeOnMainThread(() => 
                {
                   Message = "Congratulations!";
                });
            }
            else
            {
                var audioPlayer = _audioManager.CreatePlayer(await FileSystem.OpenAppPackageFileAsync("error.mp3"));
                audioPlayer.Play();

                MainThread.BeginInvokeOnMainThread(() => 
                {
                   Message = "Sorry! Invalid code!";
                });
            }
        }
        catch(Exception e)
        {
            // Handle error but I never hit this
        }
    }
}
```